# Getting $x,y$ position on an image based on given value

Tags: geometry, matrices, rotations, image-processing

This should be simple but my math skills are really bad ...

I have an image of 36 images (6 by 6 matrix). These small images are 36 instances of a direction arrow (like from Google maps GPS), each image rotated by $10^\circ$ from $0^\circ$ to $350^\circ$.

I don't know how to get image $X$ and $Y$ position of each small image when I have the rotation amount. Images are $50\times50\,\mathrm{px}$, so...

- for $10^\circ$ image is at $50\times0\,\mathrm{px}$,
- for $20^\circ$ image is at $100\times0\,\mathrm{px}$
- for $90^\circ$ image is at $150\times50\,\mathrm{px}$ (because it is on row 2)
- ...
- for $350^\circ$ image is at $250\times250\,\mathrm{px}$

What is the formula to get this $X-Y$ value?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Given that the angle of the $n$<sup>th</sup> image is $n\cdot10^\circ$ for $n=0,1,\dots,35$, you can have the $y$-index $j$ to be $\lfloor{n/6}\rfloor$ (int part of $n/6$) and the $x$-index $i$ to be $n-6j$.

You then multiply $i$ and $j$ for the respective $\Delta x$ and $\Delta j$ which in your problem is $50\,\mathrm{px}$ each.
\begin{align}
j &= \lfloor{n/6}\rfloor \\
i &= n-6j \\
x &=i\cdot50\,\mathrm{px} \\
y &=j\cdot50\,\mathrm{px} 
\end{align}

Programaticaly (this will be pseudocode, but you might be able to adapt to your language of choice):

```
for n = 0 to 35:
    j = n div 6
    i = n mod 6
    draw( rotate(figure,10*n), i*50, j*50 )
next
```

Where `n div 6` means integer division (quotient from integer division) and `n mod 6` means modulo operator (residue from integer division).  In C and other C-inspired language they are respectively `n/6` and `n%6`.  Language with no strong integer classes you might need to write `j = int(n/6)` and `i=n-6*j` .

Comment: That's probably right but looks complicated for me to understand, I guess my math knowledge is just absurdly low. I made it with a different code and I posted it as answer. Thanks. I was using PHP language btw.

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like X=(degrees mod 60)*5, Y=(degrees div 60)*50

Comment: X=(degrees mod 60)*5, as the degrees are already multiplied by 10.

Comment: yes, you're right. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, but probably because I had to do it by PHP and I am not sure I found the right mathematic equivalent. degrees mod 60 I assumed it was `$degrees % 60`, I don't know if that's right. Anyway, I was able to do it by a few different steps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by this PHP code, calculating row and column number:

```
$box_number = floor($angle/10);
$row_number = floor($box_number/6);
$col_number = $box_number-(floor($box_number/6)*6);

$image_x = 50*$col_number;
$image_y =  50*$row_number;
```

Just that at the end I had to manually force the value of `360°` to be the same as `0°` (`0x0px`)

Comment: Note that you can write `$col_number = $box_number-($row_number*6);` as you already have calculated `floor($box_number/6)`.